# Error happens when I install livewire in laravel

Tags: laravel

the error is

> @php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force No
> publishable resources for tag [laravel-assets].

Comment: According to [the docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/quickstart), that is not how you install Livewire.  The first thing it shows is `composer require livewire/livewire` - have you done that?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error With the laravel.

With the relase of `Laravel v8.5.23` they have added a command to `post-update-cmd` inside `composer.json`. So when ever if you run a composer update. Laravel will publishes the latest assests of the package that is created by them such as `horizon` and `telescope`.

So when they make changes in `assests` in above packages and tagged a release. You can use it by running the `composer update` command. But the changes made to `vue files and styling` will not be changed. You need to run the publish command manually. So to fix that they have added tags to those packages and whenever you run a `composer update` command it will automatically publishes the assets which are tagged as `aravel-assets`.

The reason you are getting **No publishable resources for tag [laravel-assets].** message is either you haven't installed any of the package that uses the tag `laravel-assets` or may be not update in the assets.

You can view the PR's here

1. [laravel/laravel/pull/5654](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/5654)
2. [laravel/horizon/pull/1045](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/5654)
3. [laravel/telescope/pull/1105](https://github.com/laravel/telescope/pull/1105)