# Composer | php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force

Tags: php

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awrg7.png)

```
$ composer require laravel/ui
Using version ^3.4 for laravel/ui
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laravel/ui
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Discovered Package: laravel/sail
Discovered Package: laravel/sanctum
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: laravel/ui
Discovered Package: livewire/livewire
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Discovered Package: spatie/laravel-ignition
Package manifest generated successfully.
79 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
> @php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force
No publishable resources for tag [laravel-assets].
Publishing complete.
```

What's wrong with this? whatever is run it always shows up:

> @php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force
> No publishable resources for tag [laravel-assets].

I've searched and tried all the ways but still not resolved.

I have tried :
[Error happens when I install livewire in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70313463/error-happens-when-i-install-livewire-in-laravel)

and run :
php artisan help vendor:publish

but after that, when I run :
composer require laravel/ui

nor :
composer require livewire/livewire

or else, keep appearing :
@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force No publishable resources for tag [laravel-assets].

Please help me..